# ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i fix this problem with my code I am trying to fetch some user data from an API and display name and profile image etc to the client side but its giving me this error  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object How can I fix this problem?

```
const User = () => {

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUser();
    }, []);

    const fetchUser = async () => {
        try {
            const userDataString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
            const e = await JSON.parse(userDataString);
            const response = await fetch(`https://10.0.2.2:3000/getuser`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: e.user.email,
                }),
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data)
            setUserData(data.User)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                userData[0] ? <Text>{userData.username}</Text> : <ActivityIndicator />
            }
        </View>

    )
}

export default User
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data)` like?